# Replace Autocomplete API marker with infoWindow from Fusion Table

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api, google-fusion-tables

**Background:**

I have an agent contact database created in Fusion Tables, with attached geometry to highlight their territory. I was able to render those territories on Google Maps, as well as creating the infowindow when any of the territories is clicked.
Decided to utilize the Autocomplete API for address searching as well, which works fine, as it zooms to the location and places a marker.

**Question:**

Given that I was able to retrieve the longitude and latitude of this marker, how would I be able to get the the values from different columns to add to my infowindow HTML.

Here is the part of the code that I am having trouble with:

```
marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

var location = place.geometry.location;
var lat = location.lat();
var lng = location.lng();

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
    query: {
       select: 'geometry, Geographic Name, Agent Name, Agent Website, Agent Phone',
       from: TableId,
       where: 'ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, CIRCLE(LATLNG(' + lat + ', ' + lng + '),1))'
    }
});
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_collection-map2e_FT.html)? (replacing the geocoder result with the autocomplete result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best way would be to use the [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference), specifically the [`DataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable) object to get Fusion Table data with a spatial query.

Here is a [simple sample JSbin](http://jsbin.com/noluhuricu/edit?html,output). Here, I'm showing a simple `FusionTableLayer` representing Canadian provinces with `suppressInfoWindows: true` and `clickable: false` (so the layer is for display purposes only). There's also an `Autocomplete` widget, restricted to only Canadian places. When an address is entered, a `Marker` is created with information from the `Geocoder`. Most importantly, a spatial query is made to the Fusion Table using a small circle with radius of 50m and a center of the `LatLng` returned by the `Geocoder` for the address from the dropdown menu. The data returned from the table query (the name and abbreviation of province that the small circle is contained in) is then added to the `InfoWindow` anchored on the `Marker`. The pertinent code:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.038487,-99.517295),
    zoom: 4
});

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('address'),{
    placeIdOnly: true
});
autocomplete.setComponentRestrictions({'country': ['ca']});

var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map
});

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function(event) {
  infoWindow.close();
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  if (!place.place_id) {
    return;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({'placeId': place.place_id}, function(results, status) {
    if (status !== 'OK') {
      window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      return;
    }

    marker.setPlace({
        placeId: place.place_id,
        location: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    marker.setVisible(true);
    var content = "<b>Address:</b> " + results[0].formatted_address + "<br>";

    var query = "SELECT 'Place' as place, 'Description'  as description " +
      "FROM 1GK_AefKlsiBzyufbFDuRqvF9RZTdJOUXqnIiCaO9 " +
      "WHERE ST_INTERSECTS(geometry, " +
      "CIRCLE(LATLNG(" + results[0].geometry.location.toUrlValue() + "), 50))";

    var queryText = encodeURIComponent(query);
    var gvizQuery = new google.visualization.Query(
      'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/gvizdata?tq=' + queryText);

    gvizQuery.send(function(response) {
      var table = response.getDataTable();
      content += "<b>Name (Fusion Table):</b> " + table.getValue(0,0) +
        "<br/><b>Desc (Fusion Table):</b> " + table.getValue(0,1);
      infoWindow.setContent(content);
      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: That was perfect. Had to realign my code, but it worked at the end. One question though, why does it embed "View on Google Maps" link in the infoWindow? and how to remove that?

Comment: @elrayyes I believe that is happening because of the undocumented `setPlace()` function (the code was adapted from the [Google Place ID Geocoder example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-geocoder). Take a look at this [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/zizemozite/edit?html,output) that just use `setLocation` instead.

Comment: Awesome. That was perfect. Much appreciated.